# Inside a docker, run both javascript and python

Tags: python, node.js, docker

While building a nodejs server I noticed several things were "easier to do in python". So I just created a python script for said processes.

These processes are spawned by nodejs through:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const args = [
  'BackgroundServer/main.py',
  _worker.poller_db.id,
  '--log-file=~/var/www/log/background.log'
];
if (maxRuns !== undefined) {
  args.push(`--max-num=${maxRuns}`);
}
const pythonProcess = spawn('BackgroundServer/venv/bin/python', args);
```

This works perfectly fine in my develop system; the python process starts, runs and works neatly.

Moving to a docker however poses a serious problem, obviously the venv is added to the `.dockerignore` (like it is to `.gitignore`).

The solution is to "build" the virtual environment on the spot. I've tried doing that, the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR ~/dockerapp
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install && \
virtualenv -p python3 BackgroundServer/venv && \
source BackgroundServer/venv/bin/activate && \
pip install -r BackgroundServer/requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 1337
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This however fails on "virtualenv" not found command. - how would I make the virtualenv available to the "temporary" runner?

The other solution, to build virtual environment before building the docker and then *not* ignoring the virtual environment manages to "run".
However it fails by stating that it can't find several core python packages failing to start python with:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

So.. how to combine both, how to make a nodejs container that "sees" python home install and python path.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Dockerfile` you are pulling from a specific base image:

`FROM node:carbon`

The system will only contain components that are already inside the `node:carbon` image. If you want to add some additional resources (such as virtualenv), you can install these within your `Dockerfile` using the standard commands you would use on a regular system.

Since you're using a specific node image to base your image from, you might be missing some basic dependencies - these will have to also be installed within your docker container.